# Is there a filter for smoothing out data that only changes the last incoming value that isn't MovingAverage?

Tags: data, time-series, smoothing

So I'm studying financial markets and I want to smooth out some data. This can be achieved by using MovingAverage(MA) or ExponentialMovingAverage(EMA) but I'm trying to find something better.

There are other filters like GaussianFilter(GF) that smooth out the data pretty well. The problem is that when there is a new incoming value (say the price of tomorrow) if I apply the GF it changes retroactively the whole structure of the curve from the previous n days.

This is a problem for me because my strategy is based to whether or not the filtered data curve is positive or negative (I'm actually looking at something other than the price). So I need a filter that doesn't change the previous curve that have been formed (like MA or EMA does).

Does such filter exist in Mathematica? Thanks!

Comment: I think what you need is called a causal filter. This just takes in the next point and uses previous points. It does not change previous outputs. If y is the output and x the input then y(n) = a1 y(n-1)+a2 y(n-2) ... + b1 x(n) + b2 x(n-1)...  where the a1, a2 and b1 and b2  are coefficients. An example would be a Butterworth filter. This is an example of an Infinite Impulse Response filter. Am I along the correct lines?

Comment: So you want to remove the high frequency content. [LowpassFilter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LowpassFilter.html) may be useful for this.

Comment: I'll do some research on causal filters, I think they are what I'm searching for, thanks.
On the other hand, I tried the LowPassFilter but it doesn't seem to work in this case for what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your are wrong that a gaussian filter will change all data if one more data points is added. If you have a filter of radius: r, then only the last r data points of the old data are changed, if you add a n additional data point.

Here is an example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
GaussianFilter[d0 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10], 3]

{0.280112, 0.0389168, -0.128759, -0.313144, -0.452882, -0.454627, \
-0.360839, -0.236585, -0.0574808, 0.162577}

GaussianFilter[Append[d0, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]], 3]

{0.280112, 0.0389168, -0.128759, -0.313144, -0.452882, -0.454627, \
-0.360839, -0.270588, -0.191174, -0.182346, -0.326198}

    GaussianFilter[Append[d0, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]], 3]
```

You see, all data up to: -0.360839 remain the same.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice it was only the last r values, I was only looking and the graph and how it change dramatically (I was using a large r).